# Can the image and preimage of a function be the empty set?

Tags: functions, definition

For example, if I define a function $f(x) = -x$ with a domain and codomain of positive numbers (in other words a nonexistant image and preimage) would this still be a function?

Comment: The only function with empty  domain and codomain is the empty function.  That is, a function is defined as a set of ordered pairs, no two of which have the same first element.  The empty set satisfies this condition, and in this context, it's called "the empty function."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not a function.

In particular $f(1)$ is not well-defined as the rule maps outside the codomain. It does not have exactly one output.